# convert java domain model from domain A to domain B

Tags: java, dns, transform, converters

I have a domain model A which I want to transform into another domain model B. So for each model element I need to convert it into one or a number of elements of B.

Domain A looks very simplified like:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<ModelElement> elements;
}

public class ModelElement
{
    public SubElement subElement;
}

public class SubElement
{
    public String someData;
}
```

Domain B looks like

```
public class Layout
{
    public List<Layer> layers;
}

public class Layer
{
    public LayerData layerData;
}

public class LayerData
{
    public int layerNumber;
    public String name;
}
```

This is really simplified, my models are a bit more complex, but for explaining I think it is enough.

So my question is, what is a good approach for the converter.

I thought writing a single class, which traverses through the model and converts each element. By the end I have a huge converter class, which is not so nice.

My other approach was to build a factory, which gives for each element of Domain A a specific converter. Each converter can then call the factory to get the converter for sub elements. Unfortunately I need for some element conversions additional data. So to use it in some converters I must pass them through all the upper converters, which does not sound very nice as well.

What would be a good way to do it?

Thanks for help
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data modle is hierarchical and finite I'd go with the **first approach, but divide its responsibilities down to several classes**. Have the main class publishing the data needed to convert. Then it calls a converter class for the root (Model/Layout) which converts and calls sub-converters (ModelElement/Layer level) and so on. The trick is to always pass a reference to the main class, which will work like an envelope or data store to the converters. By doing so, you'll get a **nice, decoupled design with single responsiblites**: providing data, converting a single class and so on.

This is only a sketch of the design I'd go. It's the best I can draw given the information. You may want to **adapt it** and maybe add some abstraction (e.g. interfaces with reduced data publishing for the envelope class).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [DOZER](http://dozer.sourceforge.net). The lib will allow wildcard transformation of fields (if they share the same name) and also permit custom converter.